# Is there a specific term for the car loops at an airport?

Tags: civil-engineering

I notice that many airports allow cars to loop around the arrivals/departures. Is there a specific term for this design feature in airports?

Comment: You mean the 15 minute parking to drop people off/pick them up?

Comment: I'm thinking of the actual road that connects the departures/arrivals/parking. See for instance this [fly-through video for a project at the Melbourne airport](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3dknbRW-10). Nearly every major airpot I have been to allows drivers to loop back an access different parts of the airport.

Perhaps there is no better term than "loop road" in this case.

Comment: I would have called it a foyer at an hotel or house and I  this case it is just on a grander scale